# Database first and ORMs

Tags: sql, database, nhibernate, orm

When building enterprise solutions, DB architect makes ER model and use SQL way of creating tables, procedures, views, indexes etc.

Is it possible to map that kind of entities to classes(i.e. POCO) with nHibernate? Or how to make your own mapping tool?

p.s. i don't want to use DB first EF solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tools like [Visual NHibernate](http://www.slyce.com/) or [NHibernate Mapping Generator](http://nmg.codeplex.com/) to generate the mappings from database. Such tools are not perfect but they can do most of the work for you and then you can modify the mappings they generate if needed.